# Django deployment on heroku not working

Tags: django, heroku

I created a personal portfolio website for myself using django and it also includes a blog. You can see the exact directory listing and source code in my github repository by clicking [here](https://github.com/ikushum/First-django-website)

I have the procfile and the requirements.txt file as said in the heroku website and did the following in command prompt as directed by heroku :

```
$ heroku login 
$ heroku git:clone -a appname
$ cd appname
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
```

Then collectstatic --noinput error occurred so I did this:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

Then I again repeated the deployment process and this time the deployment was successfull. And then I opened the app but the website did not appear. Instead [this](https://ikushum.herokuapp.com/) appeared.

Please help me deploy this website.

Comment: Does the app work locally in development?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes locally it works perfectly

Comment: @DanielRoseman The page has nothing to do with php....I can give a html extension anytime.....Is that why the app's not working in heroku ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably developing on Windows. Heroku, like most deployment environments, uses Linux; in that environment the file system is case-sensitive. Your Templates directory should be called "templates".

Please note also you should not be committing a lot of this stuff to either Github or Heroku. In particular the venv directory at the base level, and the pycache directories inside each directory, should be excluded. You can use the git exclude functionality to ensure they are not added.

Also it is very strange that you have named your templates with ".php" extensions. There is no PHP involved here.

Comment: okay thanks....I will do as you said and try deploying again.....I hope it works this time....I will tell you what happens. :)

Comment: Guess what ?
It worked. You can check it out here : https://ikushum.herokuapp.com/
But there is another problem now...The CSS and javascript files are not working....Please help me deal with this....and thanks again

Comment: Well I don't know why you are surprised, you disabled collectstatic. Nevertheless, read this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: So how do I enable collectstatic. I cant find how its done anywhere.

Comment: Yes I read the documentation...Added the codes in settings.py as said in the first part also did $ heroku config:set DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1... Still didn't work. However I didn't look at Whitenoise section